# How to calculate in java a Bcrypt password compatible with Laravel

Tags: java, php, android, laravel, bcrypt

I have a system built in laravel and I have created an API. The problem is in Authentication.

I have an Android app and want to authenticate with the laravel system by the following way:

user type its password and username in Android app, password and username are send over network to laravel (the password will hashing with bcrypt). In server side, laravel get the user with the username received and compare the password received with the password stored in data base.

Laravel use bcrypt in order to hash user's passwords. If I understand the bcrypt algorithm it use a number of round and a salt, so investigate laravel's code I found that it use round = 8 by default but I don't know what salt it use. I tried a web bcrypt generator for a determinate password and it doesn't match with the hash calculate by laravel (and stored in data base).

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: The salt is (or at least should be) random for every hash you create.

Comment: I expected that response. But I need how `Auth::attempt($user)` works. It receive a $user object with plain password, hash it and compare with passwords in data base (I need how hash the password in order to implement in my Android app).

Comment: Why do you need to hash it in android?

Comment: If I don't hash the password, it will send as plain password over network, and somebody can sniff it.

Comment: Woah woah woah. stop. That's what SSL|TLS is for.

Comment: Yes, I use SSL connection but I also send the password hashed

Comment: I will ask again: why?

Comment: There is a well-know technique in order to crack ssl traffic (it is called SSL Strip), so I want hash my password before it will send over network.

Comment: Do you know *how* SSL strip attacks work? It's impossible to prevent something if you don't know how it is done.

Comment: I have a little idea. But I don't know how it works in deep.

Comment: Well best advice I can give and last thing I will say about this is: look into how the attack works and how it doesn't work instead of trying to monkey patch something.

Comment: @RdIP SSL strip can only work if you're doing something stupid (i.e. mixing both encrypted and unencrypted resources). If you care about security, *never* serve some resources on a given host as unencrypted while encrypting others. Use TLS *correctly* and SSL strip won't be effective.

Answer (score 1):

I need made a workaround here to work, because when I generate with PHP, hash starts with $2y$ and java starts with $2a$.

To solve this, I create a regex in java before password match to replace $2y$ to $2a$ and works for me.

In PHP I used the native function:

`$hash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`

and in java I used jbcrypt lib.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me using `Bcrypt.checkpw("plain_password", "encrypted_password")`. I replaced the **bcrypt** encrypted hash with **$2a$** at the beginning.